# R: aggregate a data frame based on certain condition

Tags: r, list, dataframe, aggregate

I have a data frame. I want to aggregate one column of it based on another list.

```
df<-data.frame(X=c("a", "b", "c", "d"), Y=c(0.5, 0.4, 0.01, 0.09))
X     Y
a     0.5
b     0.4
c     0.01
d     0.09

l<-c("a", "c", "d")
```

l is the list which needs to grouped together. So, here I want to group all the elements in `df$X` that are there in l.

```
My desired result is:
X     Y
a'    0.6
b     0.4
```

Any idea on how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can "temporarily" change the relevant `X` values to the same grouping variable and then aggregate.  Here I arbitrarily choose `l[1]`, which also happens to be `"a"`

```
aggregate(Y ~ X, within(df, X <- replace(X, X %in% l, l[1])), sum)
#   X   Y
# 1 a 0.6
# 2 b 0.4
```

One upside to this use of `within()` in the `aggregate()` call is that the original `df` will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

An option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- copy(df)
setkey(setDT(df1), X)[l, X:='a'][, list(Y=sum(Y)), X]
#  X   Y
#1: a 0.6
#2: b 0.4
```