# Aggregate a data frame per unique value of a column

Tags: r

I am trying to aggregate a data frame per unique value of a column:

```
A <- c(3, 5, 3, 5)
B <- c(10, 20, 30, 40)
C <- c(100, 200, 300, 400)
DF <- data.frame(A, B, C)
DF

Sort <- sort(unique(DF[[c("A")]]))
# 3 5

# I want to produce mean per column and per unique A column value 
# A  mean B  mean C
# 3      20     200
# 5      30     300
```

I tried
[R: aggregate a data frame based on certain condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977916/r-aggregate-a-data-frame-based-on-certain-condition)

```
aggregate(B~C, within(DF, A <- Sort), mean)
```

but I failed.

Could someone help me ?

Comment: Try:aggregate(cbind(B,C)~A,DF,mean)

Comment: Yes, indeed. It works. Could you please make it an answer. You will help others too. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Shenglin Chen](https://stackexchange.com/users/5905924/shenglin-chen)

```
aggregate(cbind(B,C)~A,DF,mean)
```